# Недействительным аргумент при записи файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Простой скрипт для создание скриншота

```
import PIL.ImageGrab
import datetime

d1 = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S')

print(d1)

img = PIL.ImageGrab.grab()
img.save(str(str(d1)+'.png'), 'png')
```

При выполнение ругается на недействительным аргумент

```
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '02-01-2019_14:18:52.png'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Windows имя файла не может содержать двоеточие, нужно изменить формат, например на

```
'%d-%m-%Y_%H.%M.%S'
```